# Simplifying if else user input validation

Tags: c++, input, validation

This gets the job done for what I need it to do, but I am wondering if there is an easier/more efficient way of accomplishing the same thing.  The user inputs two numbers and they need to be between 0 and 50, if it doesnt fall within the required range it ends the prog

```
cout << "Enter the pixel coordinate (x, y): ";
cin >> usrInput1 >> userInput2;
if  (usrInput1 > 50)
{
    cout << "ERROR! 1" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else if (usrInput1 < 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR! 2" << endl;         
    return 0;
}
else if (usrInput2 > 50)
{
    cout << "ERROR! 3" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else if (usrInput2 < 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR! 4" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "Success" << endl;
    xvar = usrInput1 + usrInput2;
}
```

I was trying to do something like

```
if(! 0 > userInput1 || userInput2 > 99)
```

but obviously that didn't work out..

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: If you need all the unique error messages, then there is no alternative. Otherwise you can combine them with `||` like in sehe's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cout << "Enter the pixel coordinate (x, y): ";
cin >> usrInput1 >> userInput2;
if  ( (usrInput1 > 50) || (usrInput1 < 0)  ||
      (usrInput2 > 50) || (usrInput2 < 0) )
{
    cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
cout << "Success" << endl;
xvar = usrInput1 + usrInput2;
```

You *could* actually combine it further if you really wanted:

```
if  ((std::max(usrInput1,usrInput2) > 50) 
   || std::min(usrInput1,usrInput2) < 0))
{ 
     ...
```

in which case I would rather have a helper function

```
bool isValid(int i) { return (i>=0) && (i<=50); }

// ...
if (isValid(usrInput1) && isValid(usrInput2))
    ...
```

**Edit** Consider checking the input operations - this was missing in the OP:

```
if (!(cin >> usrInput1 >> userInput2))
{
     std::cerr << "input error" << std::endl;
}
if  ( (usrInput1 > 50) || (usrInput1 < 0)  ||
      (usrInput2 > 50) || (usrInput2 < 0) )
{
     std::cerr << "value out of range" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The input operations should really be part of the conditional as well!

Comment: @KerrekSB; nice addition. I was however sticking to the OP (how to do the _same_ more elegantly). I'll add it in for fun.

Comment: @KerrekSB how would you inlcude the input operations in the function?

Comment: @Extinct23: `if ((std::cin >> i) && (i>=0) && (i<=50))` -- but that would be rather sick, IMO. Code clarity above compact code

Comment: `if ((std::max(usrInput1,usrInput2)<=50) && (std::min(usrInput1,usrInput2)>=0)){ //success } else {//fail}`  Ors are no fun!

Comment: @BrianColvin: sure.... I'll take your word for it (BTW unformatted comments are no fun either)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd move most of it into a function:

```
bool check_range(int input, 
                  int lower, int upper, 
                  std::string const &too_low, std::string const &too_high) 
{
    if (input < lower) {
        std::cerr << too_low << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (input > upper) {
        std::cerr << too_high << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you'd use this something like:

```
if (check_range(usrInput1, 0, 50, "Error 1", "Error 2") &&
    check_range(usrInput2, 0, 50, "Error 3", "Error 4")
{
    // Both values are good
}
```

I should add that I'm not entirely happy with this. The function does really embody two responsibilities that I'd rather were separate (checking the range and reporting the error if its out of range).